# Transforming bounded sequences with the same limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Let $(a_{n,k}: n,k \ge 1)$ and $(b_{n,k}: n,k\ge 1)$ be nonnegative reals with the property that:

- $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n,k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{n,k}=1$;
- for each $k\ge 1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n,k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{n,k}=0$.

(Implicitly, each limit and each infinite sum is well defined.)

Pick now a real bounded sequence $(x_k: k\ge 1)$ and assume that $(n_t: t\ge 1)$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers such that both limits
$$
L_1:=\lim_{t\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_t,k}x_k
\quad \text{ and }\quad 
L_2:=\lim_{t\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{n_t,k}x_k
$$
exist.

> **Question.** Is it true that $L_1=L_2$?

---

*Attempt.* Using the hypothesis that the sequence $x$ is bounded and the second property of the bullets, for each $\varepsilon>0$ and integer $K>0$, there exists a positive integer $n_0=n_0(\varepsilon, K)$ such that
$$
\forall n\ge n_0, \quad 
\max\left\{
\left|\sum_{k< K}a_{n,k}x_k\right|, 
\left|\sum_{k< K}a_{n,k}x_k\right|
\right\}
\le \varepsilon
$$
Moreover, the properties in the bullet imply that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k\ge K} (a_{n,k}-b_{n,k})=0.
$$

Assume $x\neq 0$, hence $\|x\|:=\sup_n|x_n|\neq 0$. Now, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and an integer $K>0$ and note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_t,k}x_k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{n_t,k}x_k\right|
$$
is upper bounded, for all $t\ge n_0(\varepsilon,K)$ by
$$
2\varepsilon+\left|\sum_{k\ge K}(a_{n_t,k}-b_{n_t,k})x_k\right|\le 
2\varepsilon+\|x\|\cdot \sum_{k\ge K}|a_{n_t,k}-b_{n_t,k}|
$$
Is it true that the latter series is absolutely convergent to $0$ as $t\to \infty$? If the answer is affirmative, I am probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. The counterexample:

For each $n\ge 1$, let $e_n$ be the sequence which is constantly $0$ except at the $n$th position on which it is $1$.

Set $A:=(a_{n,k}: n,k\ge 1)$ as it follows: the sequence of sequences $((a_{n,k}: k\ge 1): n\ge 1)$ is $(e_1,e_3,e_3,e_5,e_5,e_7,e_7, \ldots)$.

Similarly, set $B:=(b_{n,k}: n,k\ge 1)$ so that the sequence of sequences $((b_{n,k}: k\ge 1): n\ge 1)$ is $(e_2,e_2,e_4,e_4,e_6,e_6,\ldots)$.

Fix $x=(1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$. Then $Ax$ is the constant sequence $1$ and $Bx$ is the constant sequence $0$.